# Google scripts sheets "Cell out of range"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to fetch the data out of a cell in a range, but i get an error saying the cell i'm trying to read is out of range

after opening the document the code goes

```js
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B7");

  var cell = range.getCell(2, 3);
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  Logger.log(cell);
```

and my sheet looks like this:

[image: screenshot of my sheet]

What is the error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, note that the `getCell()` method accepts arguments as follows: `row`, `column` (with 1-based `Integer` values). In case the `Range` it is called upon is in at least one dimension smaller than than the dimension size of the `getCell()` call, it throws an error.

Your `Range` dimensions are: `row` = 7, `column` = 2.

Your `getCell()` call dimensions are: `row` = 2, `column` = 3.

Thus, the cell referenced in the offset from the `Range` by 1 column.

**Useful links**

1. `getCell()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer)).